# Make a button with custom icon on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, resources, icons

I'm developing an android app and want to add a `button` (widget?) with icon.
As i understand, it's appearance should be described in `xml` resources.
I can do it in `java` code, but it seems incorrect.

```
public class VideoButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {
 private void onCreate(){
    setBackground(ResourceManager.getDrawable(R.mipmap.roundbackgroundnormal));
    Drawable icon = ResourceManager.getDrawable(R.mipmap.video);
    icon.setBounds(6,0,50,44);
    setCompoundDrawables(icon,null,null,null);
    setPadding(12,8,8,8);
...
```

So, i wrote an xml replacement code that doesn't fit my expectations

```
        <blah.blah.blah.ui.widgets.VideoButton
            android:id="@+id/record"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/roundbackgroundnormal"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/video"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

I expect this (ty java),

[image: а button with normal-sized centered icon]

but get this

[image: a button with a tiny icon on left]

How to fix my xml code to get a proper result?
TY, if possible fix terminology.

Comment: I suggest you consider using the Floating Action Button as @Nilesh suggested (for your particular case). Why? Because you are mixing both a background and an image drawable as your icon. As such you have a problem that you need to use drawableStart/End/Top/Bottom and hack with paddings which will never look nice on different screen densities. 

Your other option is to create a xml drawable file that will have your icon and the background colour you chose and set that as a background to your custom button.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use [**`FloatingActionButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.

Compile this dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

SAMPLE CODE

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_box_black_24dp" />
```

RESULT

[image]

---

> OR

You can use [**`ImageButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

> Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the android:src attribute in the  XML element or by the setImageResource(int) method.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_box_black_24dp" />
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<blah.blah.blah.ui.widgets.ViseoButton
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/roundbackgroundnormal"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/video"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

You can design with your custom icon.png and move it into your project folder
**mipmap**

android:background="@**mipmap**/roundbackgroundnormal"